# Can CiviContribute and CiviGrant work together?

Tags: civicontribute, civigrant

I'm part of a non-profit that takes in donations from corporations, and runs an internship program twice a year. We usually have around 15-20 different organizations offering internships. Our donors can specify whether they want their funds to go a specific organization participating in this internship round, earmark it for a project in future rounds, or put it in the general fund. Often, part of the donation goes towards into a travel fund which is allocated from later.

It sounds like we want to use CiviGrant to track what part of our budget is allocated to specific project internships, and perhaps use it to track our travel expense requests. We also need to track the invoicing status for our donors, which sounds like we need CiviContribute.

Can the two modules work together? For example, could I record a promised donation from company X that is earmarked for project Y and Z?

We also need to get a sense for how much money we have left in the general fund for improvement projects once we fulfill our grants and receive all our outstanding invoices. Is there an easy way to create a report or something similar combining data from CiviGrant and CiviContribute?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get what you want by using a Campaign for each 'donation' and then you can mark other entities with that.

Also worth noting that if CiviGrant doesn't quite match your use case, other users have switched to just using Activities, or CiviCase to create their own custom 'grant' workflow.